# Install brctl for OpenWrt - which package?

Tags: networking, openwrt, bridge, opkg

I'm getting an error in OpenWRT Attitude Adjustment that says:

```
-ash: brctl: not found
```

when I run

```
brctl addif br-lan mesh0
```

I tried:

```
opkg update
opkg install brctl
```

But I got this error:

```
Unknown package brctl
```

Is brctl in a larger package? If so, what package do I need to install use it?

Also, for future reference, is there a manual or something that lists what functions are in what packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately OpenWRT information on packages can be quite sketchy and `opkg` doesn't have a facility to search for a file in packages that are not yet installed, which doesn't help.

I don't have access to a system running Attitude Adjustment (12.09), but on my routers running Barrier Breaker (14.07), `brctl` is provided by BusyBox:

```
# opkg search /usr/sbin/brctl
busybox - 1.22.1-2
# ls -l /usr/sbin/brctl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  17 Oct  2  2014 /usr/sbin/brctl -> ../../bin/busybox
```

I believe it should be the same on Attitude Adjustment but some [searching revealed](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=42551) that a full version of `brctl` is available in the `bridge` package. To install:

```
# opkg update
# opkg install bridge
```

If you did have a `brctl` symlink in `/usr/sbin`, you'd need to remove it before installing though.